# Scope and IIFEs in JS: which values persist outside function block?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I was building my own jQuery plugin and got to wondering how the changes to the $ object persist outside the IIFE:

```
(function($){
  //plugin
 }(jQuery);
```

so I played around in a JS REPL, and found that changes to objects and arrays persist outside an IIFE, but changes do strings do not:

```
var obj={a:1,b:2};

(function(obj){obj.c=3})(obj);

**obj**
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

arr=[1,2]
[ 1, 2 ]

(function(arr){arr.push(3)})(arr);

**arr**
[ 1, 2, 3 ]

str='aoeu'
'aoeu'

(function(str){str+='aoeu'})(str);

**str**
'aoeu'
```

Could someone please explain to me the difference here between objects, arrays and strings??

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/3951400

Comment: Because strings are primitive, the `str` in the _function_ has a different reference to the `str` outside of the _function_. This means the `+=` operator never touches value of the outside identifier. If you're familiar with other languages, if `typeof foo; // "object"` then the param is _ByRef_, otherwise it is _ByVal_

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIFEs; you might want to fix up the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with primitive types (strings, numbers, etc) you are working with their value - however with more advanced data types like arrays and objects, you are working with their reference.

I'd recommend reading this chapter, it explains the differences in much greater detail:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm

Answer (score 0):

When `typeOf` argument being passed is of type `Array` or `Object` then reference(pointer) of the value is passed not the `value`. Hence if reference is updated, it means value which is being held by `reference` is updated.

In case of the `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` values is being passed as an argument hence value of the variable which hold the earlier value remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparison is wrong. You are performing very different operations. In your object example you do

```
obj.c = 3
```

You are **reading** from `obj` and mutate the object. You are not creating a new object.

In your string example you do

```
str += 'aoeu'
```

Here you are **writing** to `str`, overriding its previous value with a new string value. That's a completely different operation than what you do with the object.

If you were doing the same operation with the object, you would get a similar result. The equivalent example would rather be something like

```
obj = {a: obj.a, b: obj.b, c: 4};
```

---

**Assigning** a new value to variable, *never* updates the value of another variable:

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
foo = 21;
```

`bar` will stay `21`. It doesn't matter which value `foo` had at the beginning (number, string, object, ...).

However, there are two aspects of **objects** that are important to understand: Objects are

- mutable
- represented as reference

That means if you have an object and assign it to another variable:

```
var foo = {};
var bar = foo;
```

`foo` and `bar` now point to the same object in memory. Because objects are *mutable*, they can be changed "in place":

```
bar.x = 5;
console.log(foo.x);
```

**Primitive values** (anything that is not an object), are *immutable*. They cannot be changed in place:

```
var foo = "abc";
foo[0] = "x";
console.log(foo); // still "abc", not "xbc"
```

Because of immutability, "changing" a value implies creating a new value. That new value has to be "put" somewhere, which is often done be assigning it to the same variable:

```
foo = 'x' + foo.substring(1);
```

Or put in other words: Immutable values force us to assign new values to variables.